# Customer cannot pay by card without sign-in using PayPal Website Payments Standard

Tags: magento, paypal, payment

PayPal mentions, by using PayPal Website Payments Standard (WPS), when your customers check out, they will be directed to a page that allows them to log into their PayPal account OR pay by credit card without having to sign up for a PayPal account.

However, my shoping cart integrated with WPS has no place for customer entering credit card info?
It always want customer to sign-in or create a new account for payment.
(PayPal Website Payments Standard is supposed to allows users the choice of signing in or not signing in.)

What goes wrong? Am I missing any things?

Background:

Paypal account: Paypal Australia (Preimer)
Shoping cart: Magento. It has preconfigured Paypal payment method. I use WPS for check out payment method.

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you're already using Magento, why not use Express Checkout? It's free as well, and a lot more secure. Just get your API credentials through Profile > My selling tools > API Access > Update > Request API credentials > Request API Signature and enter them in your Magento backend.
2. Check whether "PayPal account optional" is switched on in your PayPal account. PayPal > Profile > My selling tools > Website Payment Preferences > Update.

Comment: Can Express Checkout accept credit cards? (Without sign-in)

Comment: Yes. Ensure you enable it in the Express Checkout settings within your Magento backend, though. ("Enable PayPal Guest Checkout? => Yes")